# handing variable in ngModel angular 2

Tags: angular

I try pass params variable item.audutModel in [(ngModel)] and catch value of [(ngModel)] by (ngModelChange)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)" but in (ngModelChange)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)" it understand item.audutModel is name Model not params . Sorry for my English. If you can't understand please ask in comment.

my code :
html file

```
         <tr *ngFor="let item of Room">
                            <td>{{item.RoomNumber}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <ion-item>
                                    <ion-label class="font-w">Số người lớn</ion-label>

                                    <ion-select [ngModel]="item.audutModel" (ngModelChange)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)">
                                        <ion-option value="1">1 người</ion-option>
                                        <ion-option value="2">2 người</ion-option>
                                        <ion-option value="3">3 người</ion-option>
                                    </ion-select>
                                </ion-item>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ion-item>
                                    <ion-label class="font-w">Số trẻ em</ion-label>
                                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]=item.childModel (ngModelChange)="AddChild(item.childModel)">
                                        <ion-option value="1">1 trẻ em</ion-option>
                                        <ion-option value="2" *ngIf="  this.Adults == 1 || this.Adults == 2 ">2 trẻ em</ion-option>
                                        <ion-option value="3" *ngIf="  this.Adults == 1 ">3 trẻ em</ion-option>
                                    </ion-select>
                                </ion-item>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{this.price}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                    <button ion-button class="add-room" (click)="AddRoom()">Add Room</button>
                    <button ion-button class="delete-room">Delete Room</button>
                </ion-row>
```

ts file

```
     AddAdults(Adults){
    this.Adults = Adults;

    this.pricePerAd = 200;
    this.price = 1000 + Adults*this.pricePerAd;
  }
  AddChild(child){
  this.pricePerCh = 100;
  this.price += child*this.pricePerCh;
  }
  AddRoom(){
    this.audutModel = "audut";
    this.childModel = "child";
    this.RoomNumber = this.RoomNumber + 1 ;
    this.audutModel =   this.audutModel + this.RoomNumber;
    this.childModel = this.childModel + this.RoomNumber;
    this.object.audut = this.audutModel;
    this.object.child = this.childModel;

    this.Room.push( this.object);
```

}

Comment: you should add the tag "angular2" to your issue

Comment: @MTroy There is no "angular2" tag anymore, it's just "angular" which refers to angular >= 2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the $event to the method.

```
<ion-select [ngModel]="item.audutModel" (ngModelChange)="AddAdults($event)">
```